# How do I add :hover on the nth child of an element using CSS2 selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to give each menu li a unique background color on hover, and I want to do it using css2.

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
</ul>
```

I was able to add a background onto the first element, using the following:

```
nav ul > li:hover:first-child a { background-color:red !important; }
```

When I add a different background onto the 2ndelement, the hover effect for the next element appears only when I place my cursor over the first element.

This is my code so far:

```
nav ul > li:hover:first-child a { background-color:red !important; }
nav ul > li:hover:first-child + li a { background-color:blue !important; }
```

Is there a proper way to do this with CSS2?

I'm tried to get some insight into this Boltclock's answer in the link below.

[How do I get the nth child of an element using CSS2 selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682521/how-do-i-get-the-nth-child-of-an-element-using-css2-selectors)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nth child is represented by the last element in the `+` chain (before the combinator immediately following it, if any), so you would attach the `:hover` selector to that element like so:

```
nav ul > li:hover:first-child a { background-color:red !important; }
nav ul > li:first-child + li:hover a { background-color:blue !important; }
```

If you wish to make this clearer for the first child, you can reorder the pseudo-classes, placing `:hover` at the end (i.e. after `:first-child`):

```
nav ul > li:first-child:hover a { background-color:red !important; }
nav ul > li:first-child + li:hover a { background-color:blue !important; }
```

Lastly, as others have mentioned, you should remove the `!important`s unless you have a specific reason to use them.

Comment: 1+ For not using `nth-child`

Answer (score 2):

The way @BoltClock describes is the only way to do it **in CSS2** (as you requested) without defining classes (I personally would define classes for each list item as your solution since it's easier to maintain and easier to remember months from now how it works). If you can use CSS3, then `nth-child` is probably what you're looking for.

Your example code should look like this instead:

```
nav ul > li:hover:first-child a { background-color:red; }
nav ul > li:first-child + li:hover a { background-color:blue; }
nav ul > li:first-child + li + li:hover a { background-color:green; }
nav ul > li:first-child + li + li + li:hover a { background-color:yellow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">yellow</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">magenta</a></li>
</ul>

li:first-child:hover a { background-color: red; }
li:nth-child(5):hover a { background-color: magenta; }
```

Comment: `:nth-child()` is not a CSS2 selector.

Answer (score 0):

In your html there are no `<a>` tags, yet the css rules are trying to style a link that is not there. Give this a shot:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 5</a></li>
</ul>

li:first-child:hover a { background-color: red; }
li:nth-child(2):hover a { background-color: blue; }
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AzodoyI/1/).

Also note that you don't need to use `!important` unless you need to override another style, and this can be problematic, albeit useful at times.

Comment: `:nth-child()` is not a CSS2 selector.