# Changing Table font in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the CSS below:

```
table.Table12 { border:1px solid blue; }
table.Table12 td { border:1px solid blue;   width:200px;}
table.Table12 a:link{   font-weight: bold;}
```

and the html code below:

```
<table class="Table12" align="right">
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com/test1.php">test1</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/test2.php">test2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com/test3.php">test3</a></td>  
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/test4.php">test4</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

All work fine and I set all table to bold font;
I just need to change the font of "test3" to normal font in CSS;
Is this possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in css:

```
table.Table12 td:nth-child(3) { font-weight: normal; }
```

forget it... didnt take in account the last line of your css code.
this one works fine:

```
table.Table12 tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) a { font-weight: normal; }
```

more details about `nth-child` syntax you can find here: [How can I get the second child using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664773/how-can-i-get-the-second-child-using-css)

Comment: how to refer to this in the html?

Comment: it should do the work without making any change in html

Comment: I am testing it, not working? does it matter where I put this line in CSS?

Comment: wonderful Nik; this one changed test4; to change test3 just make the td child 1 instead of 2; thanks a lot...  +1 and accept your solution...

Answer (score 2):

Nik's answer is right, you don't need to add that in the HTML, instead, you add it to the CSS. Should be added to the end.
Like so:

```
table.Table12 { border:1px solid blue; }
table.Table12 td { border:1px solid blue;   width:200px;}
table.Table12 a:link{   font-weight: bold;}
/*Solution*/
table.Table12 td:nth-child(2) { font-weight: normal; }
```

That will work right away.

You can also add a class to it and you can recycle it for later use:

```
.normal-font{font-weight: normal}
```

And then in your html:

```
<table class="Table12" align="right">
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com/test1.php">test1</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/test2.php">test2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com/test3.php" class="normal-font">test3</a></td>  
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/test4.php">test4</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, it started counting from 0 rather than 1, I'll edit mine as well for future reference. Happy coding!