# darken background by 4% on @each ul li function? (SCSS)

Tags: sass

Using SCSS to make 4 boxed `li` elements darken their color. I can do this manually with classes but that defeats the purpose of semantics. Trying to create a @for function to handle this but I've not found any resources to do what I need.

This is my desired outcome that I want to automate through SCSS:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <img>
        <p></p>
        <a class="button"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <img>
        <p></p>
        <a class="button"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <img>
        <p></p>
        <a class="button"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <img>
        <p></p>
        <a class="button"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
li {
    &.one {
        background: $primary-color
    }
    &.two {
        background: darken($primary-color, 4%);
    }
    &.three {
        background: darken($primary-color, 8%);
    }
    &.four {
        background: darken($primary-color, 12%);
    }
}
```

There has to be a way to automate this without using classes ... maybe an incremental? Add 4% on ... ? This is where I get lost ...

Can anyone assist and explain their code? I have no idea how to even start.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `.number` classes instead of `nth-child`?

Comment: @cimmanon I want to do this without classes. This is not a duplication.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I'm unsure how to do that lol

Comment: Nth-child: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664773/how-can-i-get-the-second-child-using-css  You can use the question marked as duplicate and this link to generate what you want.

Comment: @cimmanon please correct post to show the alternative question as main, as your marked duplicate question does not provide code for classless elements.

Comment: @NathanMerrill perfect, thank you sir!

Comment: I am not obligated to do anything:  your question did not clarify what part of the problem you didn't understand (how to use a loop, how to incrementally darken, how to style elements with something other than a class, etc.).

Comment: @cimmanon seriously? dude you've caused me problems twice now. I stated in my ask that I want to do this without using a class. **If you feel obligated to edit my post then you need to feel obligated to correct it with the alternative duplicate answer, which I've stated clearly reflects my problem - and solves it**. NOT the duplicate that you inserted first.

If you won't fix it I'll get a mod to. This is absurd.

Comment: @AlexanderGraham, please check here:- https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/dvzebo2t/