# How to target a specific div out of 4 divs with the same class with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I target the 4th div (with class .col-sm-3) with CSS in following example?

```
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
    </div> <!--/.row-->
   </div> <!--/.container-->
  </div> <!--/#footer-->
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you only looking for the fourth occurrence of a div with the class `col-sm-3`, or just the fourth div child of `div.row`? Could there be other divs between the divs you've shown?

Comment: `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` or `:nth-child` selectors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the second child using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664773/how-can-i-get-the-second-child-using-css)

Comment: .col-sm-3:last-child {} did the job, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.col-sm-3:last-child {}
```

or

```
.col-sm-3:nth-child(4) {}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: You should use a more reputable source like MDN or W3 rather than W3Schools which is prone to errors

Comment: @Zach Saucier - Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 .col-sm-3:nth-child(4){}
```

Comment: You should use a more reputable source like MDN or W3 rather than W3Schools which is prone to errors